# Transfer App option not available iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I have created a app long time ago on my iTunes account and now i would like transfer it on different iTunes account. After googling i found transfer app is available at under **App information > Additional information > Transfer App**  [like here](http://cl.ly/image/0S1s3B3J2Z1F)  But i am unable to find Transfer app option on my account [like here](http://cl.ly/image/0S1s3B3J2Z1F). I have already read Criteria for Transferring an App. Please let me know what can i do.

Comment: Your app is not already published . thats why you cannot transfer it to other account .

Comment: @Muhammad, Yes i have already checked it but as for the Criteria for Transferring an App if i have app status Prepare for Submission i should able to transfer. you can check it here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

Comment: check below answer and highlighted text from the app transfer criteria

Comment: Myself i am having same issue and none of the responses answers the question.

So this question is best suited for Apple support rather than on this site since its not code related question

Answer (score 3):

Yes , Here is your solution

When you are a member under an organisation you can't able to see that option in your appstore account

Only the admin will have that access and can able to see transfer app option.

Get those admin credentials to transfer the app.

It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Only the person who has role "**Admin, Account holder**" can transfer app to another account.

Other admins cannot transfer app to another account and they cannot see **Transfer app** option under **Additional information**

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason listed in [App Transfer Criteria](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devaf27784ff) that I don't see mentioned in other answers is this:

> The App must have had at least one version that has been released to the App Store.

Make sure that you had at least one actual version published on the App Store. Published TestFlight builds don't count.